# Make explicit when a struct is truthy or falsy in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, struct

I have defined a simple struct `mystruct` in C++. I would like to be able to use

```
mystruct a; 
// do things to a
if(a) { 
    /* do things */ 
}
```

directly. Is there a way for me to define the behavior of this?

Comment: Write a explicit operator bool for your class and figure out what it means to be true.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ninja'd :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to define the behavior of this?

Yes, provide an overload for the `bool` type conversion operator:

```
class mystruct {
public:
  explicit operator bool () const {return condition; } // This is the conversion operator
};
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16615725/1413395) contains some more detailed info.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it would be something like this, but did not know the terminology to google it.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Totally understandible. The terminology gap is often a bigger problem than the problem you're solving.

Comment: I believe the `explicit` keyword (or the safe bool idiom for everyone who is stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler) should be mentioned, because it avoids a bunch of annoying problems of the non-explicit version. It’s part of the linked answer, but I believe it’s an important enough issue to at least mention it here as well.

Comment: @besc Besides it's mentioned in the linked detailed info, i've added that to my sample.